# Pass row data down to child cell component in Grid without passing as a parameter

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, meteor-blaze

I have built a simple Grid component which mostly works, however I have run into a situation where I need to pass down the instance of GridRow being rendered to the GridCell to allow the GridCell component to access it's properties and modify if necessary.

The component is constructed from 3 parts, Grid, GridBody and GridCell as follows:

Usage in index.razor

```
<Grid Items="MyItems">
    <GridBody Context="row">
        <GridCell>@row.Id</GridCell>
        <GridCell>@row.Item.Description</GridCell>
    </GridBody>
</Grid>
```

Grid.razor:

```
@namespace Accounting.Web.Components
@typeparam TItem
@attribute [CascadingTypeParameter(nameof(TItem))];

<CascadingValue Value="this" IsFixed="true">
    <table cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var row in Rows)
            {
                <tr>
                    @GridBody(row)
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</CascadingValue>
```

Grid.razor.cs

```
namespace Accounting.Web.Components
{
    public class GridRow<TItem>
    {
        public TItem Item { get; set; } = default!;
        public int Id { get; set; } = default!;
    }

    public partial class Grid<TItem>
    {
        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment<GridRow<TItem>> GridBody { get; set; } = default!;

        [Parameter]
        public IList<TItem> Items { get; set; } = default!;
    }
}
```

GridBody.razor

```
@namespace Accounting.Web.Components
@typeparam GridRow

GridBody.razor.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace Accounting.Web.Components
{
    public partial class GridBody<GridRow>
    {
        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment<GridRow> ChildContent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

GridCell.razor

```
@namespace Accounting.Web.Components
@typeparam TItem

<td>
    @ChildContent
</td>
```

GridCell.razor.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace Accounting.Web.Components
{
    public partial class GridCell<TItem>
    {
        [CascadingParameter]
        public Grid<TItem> Grid { get; set; } = default!;

        [Parameter]
        public int Id { get; set; } = default!;

        [Parameter]
        public GridRow<TItem> Row { get; set; } = default!;

        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; } = default!;
    }
}
```

In my various attempts I have attempted to pass down the row from GridBody to the GridCell but nothing has come close to working.  The only way I can accomplish what I need is to directly pass row as a parameter in the  tag in index.razor as follows:

```
<GridCell Row=row>@row.Id</GridCell>
```

This means I would ned to pass it in every GridCell.  Is there a more elegant of passing the row down to the GridCell above without the use of a parameter?

Comment: Normally, you want the children to be agnostic of the parent: they take in their values, and produce events to notify the parent if something important happens.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 I agree but in this case the grid required access to the Parent Grid it is hosted in as it will allow editing of data in that row

Comment: When you pass a reference to a cell value to the `Cell.razor` component, you can edit it by simply changing the value.  There's no need to be passing around components or renderfragments.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was straight forward, simply use a cascading value component to the Grid.razor:

Grid.razor:

```
@namespace Accounting.Web.Components
@typeparam TItem
@attribute [CascadingTypeParameter(nameof(TItem))];

<CascadingValue Value="this" IsFixed="true">
    <table cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var row in Rows)
            {
                <tr>
                    <CascadingValue Value="row">
                        @GridBody(row)
                    </CascadingValue>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</CascadingValue>
```

GridCell.razor

```
@namespace Accounting.Web.Components
@typeparam TItem

<td>
    @ChildContent
</td>
```

GridCell.razor.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace Accounting.Web.Components
{
    public partial class GridCell<TItem>
    {
        [CascadingParameter]
        public Grid<TItem> Grid { get; set; } = default!;

        [Parameter]
        public int Id { get; set; } = default!;

        [CascadingParameter]
        public GridRow<TItem> Row { get; set; } = default!;

        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; } = default!;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are being much too literal with the idea of components-as-objects.  With structured data, you should passing just the relevant data, not component objects with markup displaying the data.  A Table should have a `List <RowData>`, each Row should have a `List <CellData>`, and each Cell should have a `DataValue` If you want to edit a cell-- just go ahead and change its value.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Thanks for your input, at the moment this is a learning exercise and I have put together this grid using various tutorials to help me understand Blazor basics. - as you've noticed, I have a way to go yet, But I will definitely keep your comment in mind and attempt a revisit to this

Comment: @MusaffarPatel Some of the libraries are open source on Github.  Looking at how other people do it can be quite instructive.  I've learn an awful lot about coding patterns and techniques for deciphering other people's code!